# show value in textfield dialog when checked

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This is the checkbox

```
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" name="hour[]" class="create-daily" value="1" /><br />
<input id="c2" type="checkbox" name="hour[]" class="create-daily" value="2" /><br />
<input id="c3" type="checkbox" name="hour[]" class="create-daily" value="3" /><br />
```

I have a dialog

```
<div id="form_input" title="Konfirmasi">
 <?php $data['hour'] = $this->input->post('hour');?>
  <table>
    <?php echo form_open('booking/ok'); ?>
    <input type="hidden" value='' id="id" name="id">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sdate?>" id="sdate" name="sdate" />
    <?php echo "Anda memesan room : <br/>Tanggal :<b> ".$sdate."</b><br>";?>
    Jam : <b><span class="jambooking"></span></b>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div class="element">
            <label class="Norm">Jam:</label>
            <input type="text" name="jam" class="jambooking" id="jam" minlength="2" value="" />
            </div>

            <label class="Norm">User:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" class="required text" minlength="2" />
            </div>
```

I have javascript

```
$(".create-daily").live("click",function(){
         if ($(this).attr("checked")){
             //var date = $(this).attr("date");
             //$('#date').val(date);
            $( "#form_input" ).dialog( "open" );
            $(".jambooking").html( $(":checked").val());
            }
        });
```

I use a span and input with a class set to `jambooking`. When I checked a check box and show a dialog, the span shows a value.

When I set to the input class `jambooking` the value does not show.

How would I load a value to the text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".create-daily").live("click",function(){
     if ($(this).is(":checked")){
         var checkedVal = $(this).val();
         //$('#date').val(date);
         $( "#form_input" ).dialog( "open" );
         $("span.jambooking").html(checkedVal); //for span
         $("input.jambooking").val(checkedVal); //for textbox
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an input, you should use .val() instead of .html()

```
$(".jambooking").val( $(":checked").val());
```

Answer (score 1):

`$()`.html is for `div`. `$().text` is for `<p>`. You have to use different one for input field. Use `$().val()`;

Change this one.

From

```
$(".jambooking").html( $(":checked").val());
```

To

```
$("input.jambooking:text").val( $(":checked").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
$(".jambooking").val( $(":checked").val());
```

or check this link [Jquery Text Editor](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-text-editor-plugins/)

Hope it works.